# How to install lumibot properly?

Tags: python, pip, trading, algorithmic-trading, pylance

I am struggling to install lumibot for a stock trading bot app I want to put on my resume. Is there any chance any of you have some insight into how to go about doing this? Below I have attached screenshots of all the issues I'm getting.

```
-- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 177, in emit
    self.console.print(renderable, overflow="ignore", crop=False, style=style)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/console.py", line 1673, in print
    extend(render(renderable, render_options))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/console.py", line 1305, in render
    for render_output in iter_render:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 134, in __rich_console__
    for line in lines:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/segment.py", line 249, in split_lines
    for segment in segments:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/console.py", line 1283, in render
    renderable = rich_cast(renderable)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/protocol.py", line 36, in rich_cast
    renderable = cast_method()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/self_outdated_check.py", line 130, in __rich__
    pip_cmd = get_best_invocation_for_this_pip()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/entrypoints.py", line 58, in get_best_invocation_for_this_pip
    if found_executable and os.path.samefile(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/genericpath.py", line 101, in samefile
    s2 = os.stat(f2)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/pip'
Call stack:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/pip", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 70, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 101, in main
    return self._main(args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 223, in _main
    self.handle_pip_version_check(options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 190, in handle_pip_version_check
    pip_self_version_check(session, options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/self_outdated_check.py", line 236, in pip_self_version_check
    logger.warning("[present-rich] %s", upgrade_prompt)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/logging/__init__.py", line 1489, in warning
    self._log(WARNING, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/logging/__init__.py", line 1624, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/logging/__init__.py", line 1634, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/logging/__init__.py", line 1696, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/logging/__init__.py", line 968, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 179, in emit
    self.handleError(record)
Message: '[present-rich] %s'
```

This is the output I received after running 'pip install lumibot'. I read that lumibot can only work with Python 3.10 but I am stuck to using Python 3.11. I can't change it for some reason, I tried to uninstall 3.10 from my 'Applications' folder (as I am using MacOS) and this didn't work. When I run 'python --version', I still get 'Python 3.11.3'.

I will say however that prior to the errors above, I got a bunch of these messages:

```
Requirement already satisfied: click>=8.1.3 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from Flask->flask-marshmallow->lumibot) (8.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: blinker>=1.6.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from Flask->flask-marshmallow->lumibot) (1.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Babel>=1.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from Flask-BabelEx>=0.9.3->flask-security->lumibot) (2.12.1)
Requirement already satisfied: speaklater>=1.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from Flask-BabelEx>=0.9.3->flask-security->lumibot) (1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: WTForms in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from Flask-WTF>=0.13.1->flask-security->lumibot) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: webencodings in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from html5lib>=1.1->yfinance>=0.2.18->lumibot) (0.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-engineio>=4.3.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from python-socketio>=5.0.2->flask-socketio->lumibot) (4.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: bidict>=0.21.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from python-socketio>=5.0.2->flask-socketio->lumibot) (0.22.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography>=2.6.1->ccxt==3.0.61->lumibot) (2.21)
Requirement already satisfied: anyio<5.0,>=3.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from httpcore>=0.17.3->dnspython>=2.0.0->email-validator->lumibot) (3.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: h11<0.15,>=0.13 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from httpcore>=0.17.3->dnspython>=2.0.0->email-validator->lumibot) (0.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from Jinja2>=3.1.2->Flask->flask-marshmallow->lumibot) (2.1.3)
```

This output again comes when I run 'pip install lumibot'. So, it seems like some of it is installing, but still in VS Code when I try and use lumibot I get the following error:

```
Import lumibot could not be resolved (Pylance)
```

Once I get this fixed I can properly start my trading project and finally finish my resume for apps, so if anyone can help, it would be much appreciated!

In summary, I've tried to install lumibot, but for some reason, it's the only module that my computer just can't recognise. Pandas works, alpaca-py works, quantstats works and requests works. But still, lumibot doesn't!

Initially, I got 'aohttp' errors or something like that, but I managed to read up online to find some commands past that. When I ran a command I found online to install it I thought I was home free, as I wasn't getting any errors and I restarted my computer a couple times to reflect upgrades I made to my pip and Python version. But still, no cigar.

Comment: try Webull's API, imo it's better than alpaca, yfinance, etc. and it's also free.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```bash
pip3 install lumibot
```

and that should work.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue when I ran the pip install from the command prompt. However, when I ran pip install from the visual studio terminal in the project where I intended to use lumibot, then it worked just fine.